# Bind object's properties with values from other object's properties

Tags: javascript

I want to get all `data-bind` key value pairs as object using `eval` and bind this `object's` properties to the same properties from the `model` object.

```
<div data-bind="innerHTML: text, style: { color: color }"></div>

Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('[data-bind]')).forEach(function (el) {
    var model = { text: 'text', color : 'red' }
    var boundData = eval('({' + el.getAttribute('data-bind') + '})');
}
```

Final result should be:

`boundData.text` to be equal to the model's property text property

`boundData.color` to be equal to the model's property color property

This example gives me `Uncaught ReferenceError: text is not defined`

Comment: And? What's the problem? Where you stuck?

Comment: it gives me Uncaught ReferenceError: text is not defined

Comment: Of course it does, you're eval'ing `({innerHTML: text, style: { color: color }}`, which is code that expects an in-scope variable called `text` and another in-scope variable called `color`.

Comment: But how to make it to search in the context of model ?

Answer (score 1):

If you're already planning to use `eval`, I figure you probably won't mind using the other thing most JavaScripters stay away from: `with`. Like `eval`, *very constrained use* of `with` can be appropriate. In this case, it does the job:

```
Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('[data-bind]')).forEach(function (el) {
    var boundData, model = { text: 'text', color : 'red' }
    with (model) {
        boundData = eval('({' + el.getAttribute('data-bind') + '})');
    }
});
```

The resulting `boundData` will have `innerHTML` and `style` properties (where `style` is an object with a `color` property), you'll have to adjust them to get it to have `text` and `color` properties.

Example:

```js
var dataBindValue = "innerHTML: text, style: { color: color }";
var boundData, model = { text: 'text', color : 'red' }
with (model) {
  boundData = eval('({' + dataBindValue + '})');
}
snippet.log("boundData.innerHTML = " + boundData.innerHTML);
snippet.log("boundData.style.color = " + boundData.style.color);
```

```html
<!-- Script provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

---

FWIW, [here's the case against using `with` generally](http://www.yuiblog.com/blog/2006/04/11/with-statement-considered-harmful/).